# How to show JFrame like spotlight on current window?

Tags: java, swing

I have set `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`;

[image: Here is the description]

Comment: Use a [`JPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html) for that.

Comment: JPopupMenu just show on jframe but i want jframe show on the top of the current window like spotlight or alfred.